# Chantation or singing Baruch Adonai L'Olam

Tags: tefilla, maariv

Within the prayer Baruch Adonai L'Olam (Maariv) there is this part reading   ברוך יי ביום ברוך יי בלילה ברוך יי בשכבנו ברוך יי בקומנו  what I would like to know it there is some melody to sing or chant this? (Or for the whole prayer).

Comment: Hi Levi. What have you tried? Have you searched YouTube? There are usually some renditions there of various tefillos, although I might add you should be careful of Messianic (fake Jewish) tunes.

Comment: Here's one - never heard it before: http://web.nli.org.il/sites/nlis/he/btz/Pages/Song.aspx?songId=Bait_Lazemer003825902&SysNum=003825902#songId=Bait_Lazemer003825902&SysNum=003825902

Comment: @ezra no luck on youtube, searched on Google but didn't find any melodies/tunes

Comment: The link posted by @Danny Schoemann is a heavy cantorial melody. I assume Levi was more interested in a nusach that the congregation could join in on, or that a (non-cantor) Chazan could reasonably use. For example, I know of about eight such "accessible" melodies for Sim Shalom, and I have heard one heavy cantorial version which I would not be interested in at all.

Comment: @MarkFischler Your correct, maybe someone can help me out with that.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on some musical search site.

Comment: @Danny Schoemann: Is there a musical search site specializing in nusach for the Hebrew liturgy (particularly everyday and Shabbos melodies)? I'd be very interested to find it.

Comment: @MarkFischler - A Google search for "Hebrew liturgy mp3" brings - in the top 5 links 4 sites that claim just that: http://www.sidduraudio.com, http://www.shulmusic.org, http://teruah-jewishmusic.blogspot.com/2010/01/learning-jewish-liturgy-online.html and http://www.chazzanut.com  - though I didn't go to any of them.